# Angular 2 Set focus on first field of form on component load

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

In my app I want to automatically set focus on first field of form on component load. Can anyone please guide how to achieve this without any repetition as I want this on every form (Reactive Forms) in my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an directive to achieve this behavior.

This will show you the way how to do it: https://plnkr.co/edit/ttxCP7vCLkLtNb3Xiaah?p=preview

```js
import {Component, NgModule, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Directive({
  selector: 'form[anyNameHere]'
})
export class SelectFirstInputDirective {

  constructor(private _eRef: ElementRef, private _renderer : Renderer) { }

  private _getInputElement(nativeElement: any): any {
    if (!nativeElement || !nativeElement.children) return undefined;
    if (!nativeElement.children.length && nativeElement.localName === 'input' && !nativeElement.hidden) return nativeElement;

    let input;

    [].slice.call(nativeElement.children).every(c => {
      input = this._getInputElement(c);
      if (input) return false; // break
      return true; // continue!
    });

    return input;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let formChildren = [].slice.call(this._eRef.nativeElement.children);

    formChildren.every(child => {
      let input = this._getInputElement(child);

      if (input) {
        this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(input, 'focus', []);
        return false; // break!
      }

      return true; // continue!
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <form anyNameHere>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input hidden formcontrolname="firstName" type="text" class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="firstName">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9 form-inline">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input formcontrolname="firstName" type="text" class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input formcontrolname="lastName" type="text" class="form-control input-sm ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, SelectFirstInputDirective ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mxii. Apparently the above directive should set the focus on first input field in the form and it does it in the plunker. But when I tested it in my app it didn't work, probably because in my case the input field is under a div tag. Is there any way to query and select the input elements only and then set focus to first input. Currently you are using this._eRef.nativeElement.children which selects all children of  the form.

Comment: See my updated answer/plunker.. you need to do a recursive search! :)

Comment: Still no success, I logged, value of input after this line in directive and let input = this._getInputElement(child); and its undefined. Please have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/YF7M4ph7891x03hjJr6A?p=preview

Comment: Please also guide how to skip the hidden inputs? Since if the first input is hidden it would set focus to that, which isn't visible on screen.

Comment: One more thing, Angular team sdiscourage the use of ElementRef this is what I found in comments "Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Use templating and
 data-binding provided by Angular instead. Alternatively you take a look at {@link Renderer}  which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not  supported." Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling between your application and rendering
 layers which will make it impossible to separate the two and deploy your application into a
 web worker.

Comment: My fault, updated! And its now checking the hidden property.. you are right, but we are using the `Render` here !! It should be the last resort to MANIPULATE with ElementRef, not to check those childs and so on..

Comment: Thank you so much @mxii but it work sometimes and sometimes it doesnt work. Please have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/vvdq8IMsGjDAAM2YiO1P?p=preview

Comment: Cause in that example you are using `type="hidden"` instead of the attribute `hidden` !! See this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/azdVcdRSgER13qAcM97a?p=preview  I just pointed you to the idea, everything else is now your job! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much mxii that was really helpful. Actually I was not sure what other properties does nativeElement support. localName, hidden and type seems to cover all cases. I added support for select and text area as well :)

Comment: Definitely works but wow what bloat just to set focus of an input!

Comment: @mxii it works when page reload, but doesn't work without reload, M I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks it works for inputs but this does not focuses textarea. Can you please update for textarea also?

Comment: @faizan Just replace the ```.localName === 'input'``` to ```'textarea'```

Answer (score 9):

> you can achieve this by simply adding the "autofocus" attribute to your input element like.

```
<input class="form-control" [formControl]="name" autofocus>
```

Comment: The input will get the focus only after the page is loaded. But if you navigate in your application and return of the page, then the input will not longer receive focus.
autofocus is not well adapted for single page application.

Comment: you can create a ref to your input in the view

<input #myname>

and then you can access it in your component class

@ViewChild('myname') input; 

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.input.focus;
}

Comment: this is only useful when you are hard coding your inputs rather than dynamically generating with ngFor

Answer (score 2):

HTML  [autofocus attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) do exactly that

`<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus>`

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'form[appFocusFirstInput]'
})
export class FocusFirstInputDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const input = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    if (input) {
      input.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 4，Renderer has been deprecated, so the directive way is gone. But anyhow you can always use a "quick and dirty" way: add the reference to the element you want to set focus on and just use `<reference-name>.focus()`

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form, $event); needFocus.focus()">
  <input placeholder="" formControlName="name" #needFocus>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following approaches you can use => 
1. You can do this by autoFoucs directive OR
2. Provide reference to your control like

```
 <input hidden #firstName formcontrolname="firstName" type="text" class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
```

Then in ts file declare like this

```
export class App implements OnInit{
 @ViewChild('firstName') firstNameTextbox;
  constructor() {    
  }
ngOnInit() {
this.firstNameTextbox.nativeElement.focus();
}
}
```